# If A Foreach Fails Can You Do an Else Statement?

Tags: php

I have this code for a Instagram image retriever, it works well but can fail quite badly.

```
<table border="0" width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
<?php
        function fetch_data($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }

    $access_token = "xxx.xxx.xxx";
    $display_size = "standard_resolution"; 

    $number_of_images = 7;

    $result = fetch_data("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[user]/media/recent/?count={$number_of_images}&access_token={$access_token}");
    $result = json_decode($result);

    $images = array();
    foreach($result->data as $photo)
{
    $images[] = array(
        'url'  => $photo->images->{$display_size}->url,
        'link' => $photo->link,
    );
}
?>
<a href="<?php echo $images[0]['link']; ?>" target="new"><img src="<?php echo $images[0]['url']; ?>" border="0" height="200" width="200" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="<?php echo $images[1]['link']; ?>" target="new"><img src="<?php echo $images[1]['url']; ?>" border="0" height="200" width="200" /></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><a href="<?php echo $images[2]['link']; ?>" target="new"><img src="<?php echo $images[2]['url']; ?>" border="0" height="400" width="400" /></a></td>
                                    <td valign=top>
                                    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="<?php echo $images[3]['link']; ?>" target="new"><img src="<?php echo $images[3]['url']; ?>" border="0" height="200" width="200" /></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="<?php echo $images[4]['link']; ?>" target="new"><img src="<?php echo $images[4]['url']; ?>" border="0" height="200" width="200" /></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign=top>
                                    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> <a href="<?php echo $images[5]['link']; ?>" target="new"><img src="<?php echo $images[5]['url']; ?>" border="0" height="200" width="200" /></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="<?php echo $images[6]['link']; ?>" target="new"><img src="<?php echo $images[6]['url']; ?>" border="0" height="200" width="200" /></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

So when ever this script dies, it says it fails on line 57 which line 57 is

```
 foreach($result->data as $photo)
```

is there anyway to go if this line fails then show  so an error message does not make the site look messy?

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: Maybe a try catch finally block will help you with this

Comment: `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in /home/content/90/9753290/html/bottom.php on line 57` and

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/90/9753290/html/bottom.php on line 57` are the error messages I receive when it dies lol

Comment: you can use @igavriil approach or check before the loop if result is array and contains data

Comment: a catch block sounds great but I never coded one of those before or heard of them before except for now

Comment: You should update your post to include the error message, potential answerers should not have to go through the comments to get that info (and it allows for better formatting, hence readabiltiy). Don't include *Edit:* or something similar when you do, the system has edit history for those (few) who might want to see what changed. Keep the question a single coherently readable whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreach` works only with `array` or `objects`, everything else will generates an **Error**.
It does not throws an exception : surrounding it by `try/catch` block will have no effects.

In your case you have to do like this :

```
if (is_array  ($result->data) || 
    is_object ($result->data)) {

foreach ($result->data as $photo) {
    $images[] = array ( 'url'  => $photo->images->{$display_size}->url,
                        'link' => $photo->link); 
    // Note that i have removed a comma after $photo->link
}
}else {
    // can not loop ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Traversable` interface

> **The Traversable interface**: Interface to detect if a class is traversable using foreach.

So in your case, before foreach:

```
if ($result->data instanceof Traversable) {
    // can use foreach
}
```